# Hide tokens on a 100% client-side website (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, security, token, csrf

I have an REST API in PHP and a web application that consumes this API. The problem I have is that I only want to authorize the use of the REST API for my web application (and in the future, for example a mobile app).

The point is that most of the REST API is protected against that because only requests with an `Authorization: Bearer "User token"` header can get and request resources from that user (and to my knowledge, by not using cookies to identify the session from the API side, there is no risk of CSRF attacks or any other if necessary measures are taken to deal with the storage of said token).

However, what I can do with the login, registration, etc paths? These are without sessions and that means that anyone could create users or log in from another place.

#### Question

The solution seems to be to create a token for each API client that authorizes it to use it, but if the app is fully developed in JavaScript, without server-side languages, how do I use and store this token without exposing it?

If it's with CSRF tokens in the login form, how do I implement it from a web in JavaScript so that no one else can just do the same?

Comment: You don't.  Everything on the client is exposed.  If it was not exposed, the client would not have it.

Comment: If you don't want just anyone being able to register for whatever your site is, then that suggests some sort of joining by invitation or referral process.

Comment: They can read your source, they can snoop on all traffic using browser developer tools.  If you use a free code obfuscator, they can use a matching free de-obfuscator.  You can slow them down by having the client request tokens from the server, and updating the client often to change that request process between versions.